# Full Calendar resouce timeline how to disable user select and click in background events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

i am trying to disable user to trigger select and click events in background events, but it does not seem to work. Below is my code.

```
<FullCalendar
ref={calendarRef}
plugins={[dayGridPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}
initialView='resourceTimelineDay'
events={events}
editable={true}
selectable={true}
select={selectHandler}
eventClick={clickHandler}
```

I added the display: 'background' to the events, it shows up as background on the calendar and disables user to drag event to the background event, but the user is still able to trigger selectHandler and clickHandler.

I tried setting a class name to the event and using css to disable user input but it doesnt work.

```
.disable-interaction {
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: You can't trigger "select" _inside_ an event, I assume you mean the user can click round the edges of it in the empty space. If you don't want events to be able to overlap a background event, then do something similar to the example [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap). As for clicking on events...you can't entirely disable it on background events, but it's easy to deal with: the first thing your clickHandler function could do is check the event type, and then decide whether to continue or not.